# Select minimal networks for list of IP addresses

Tags: mysql, networking, netmask

I have DB with some network info inside.
DB structure like:

```
ID | network | netmask | description | other_data
```

I need to select `description` of the smallest network to which the address belongs.

I found how to do it for one address... But how do this for multiple addresses (Not in DB) ?
Something like `WHERE ip IN ( [list of ip] )`

```
CREATE TABLE `networks` (
  `network_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `network` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mask` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `network_dec` varchar(18) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Сеть в десятичном виде.',
  `asn_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`network_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `u1` (`network`,`mask`),
  KEY `asn_id` (`asn_id`),
  KEY `network` (`network`),
  KEY `mask` (`mask`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `networks` (`network`, `mask`, `network_dec`, `asn_id`) VALUES
(INET_ATON('10.20.30.0'), INET_ATON('255.255.255.192'), 'desc_0',  1000),
(INET_ATON('10.20.30.0'), INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'),   'desc_1',  1000),
(INET_ATON('10.20.30.0'), INET_ATON('255.255.255.240'), 'desc_2',  1000),
(INET_ATON('10.20.0.0'),  INET_ATON('255.255.0.0'),     'desc_3',  2000),
(INET_ATON('10.20.0.0'),  INET_ATON('255.255.240.0'),   'desc_4',  2000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.0.0.0'),       'desc_5',  1000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.192.0.0'),     'desc_6',  5000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.224.0.0'),     'desc_7',  5000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.240.0.0'),     'desc_8',  5000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.252.0.0'),     'desc_9',  5000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.254.0.0'),     'desc_10', 5000),
(INET_ATON('10.0.0.0'),   INET_ATON('255.255.0.0'),     'desc_11', 6000);
```

Example at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b339a/5/0

Comment: For IPv4, the smallest network is `0.0.0.0/0` (there are zero network bits). Every IP address belongs to that network. I think you mean the largest network (the most network bits). There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) for how to calculate that.

Comment: smallest = with minimum IP's inside. But you right - I need MAX(mask) in query.
But how to select one row from DB with max mask ?
And how to do that for list of IP's ?

Comment: That would be the smallest hosts, but largest network. An address has two parts: network and host. The smallest network has the most hosts, and the smallest hosts has the largest network.

Comment: I can't understand... SQL for example?